# String Overrides is not overriding the "Read more" string

Tags: 7, string-overrides

I've filed a support request on drupal.org about this question, but I figured I should ask here as well because someone could know the answer.

I want to change the "Read more" link in teasers so that it says "Full story". I was pointed to the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module which supposedly makes it very simple to change the built-in strings. The UI isn't very complicated, so I'm not sure what I could possibly be doing wrong, but it's not working. I have saved the settings, flushed all caches, etc.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Is this for a custom theme? The 'Read more' link might not be going through the t() function which I believe is required.

Comment: It is a Zen theme. I have grep'd through the entire Zen theme directory for the string "Read" and "Read more" and it isn't found, so it doesn't look like the theme is setting this value.

Comment: And you are sure it's not simply a letter case issue?

Comment: I thought that too, but I've copied and pasted the text to make sure.

Comment: It works with other strings. I've tried replacing strings in the Admin UI and it works there... but just not with the "Read more" link and I can't figure out why. I've searched the entire codebase and tried replacing EVERYTHING that said "Read more" but haven't found anything which changes it.

Comment: Is there a theme hook I can override to change the text on the teaser "Read more" link? theme_more_link() isn't for teaser links.

Comment: So, it looks like the text was being set in modules/node/node.module:node_build_content() and it had way more than just "Read more" in the text. It was: t('Read more<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array('@title' => $node_title_stripped)),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might need some tweaking, but you can change the text in hook_preprocess_node(). If you set it to "Read more" you can override it with stringoverrides after, or change it to what you want at once.

In your themes template.php, add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTHEME_process_node(&$vars) {
  // Change default text of the read more link.
  if (isset($vars['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore'])) {
    $vars['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = t('Read more');
  }
}
```

Related modules:
http://drupal.org/project/readmorecontrol
http://drupal.org/project/read_more
http://drupal.org/project/linkoutreadmore

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of fighting with this, I found the source of the problem.

I believe this to be an issue in core (not really a bug, per se). In the node.module, when it is building the "Read more" link in the teaser view, it has this code in `node_build_content()`:

```
'title' => t('Read more<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array('@title' => $node_title_stripped)),
```

So when Strings Override is doing string comparison it isn't matching, because "Read more" is obviously not the same as "`Read more<span class="element-invisible"> about My Title</span>`".

I edited the node.module so isolate the "Read more" text from the rest of the HTML like so:

```
'title' => t('Read more').t('<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>', array('@title' => $node_title_stripped)),
```

Then the system is rendering two strings: "Read more" and "`<span class="element-invisible"> about My Title</span>`."

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing your findings. Although I would not recommend to hack the core files. You should be able to override the output in your theme which would be a more long lasting solution.

Comment: I looked and looked for some hook that would allow me to override that in my theme template... but couldn't find anything. That's why the issue of changing the "Read more" text is such a popularly asked question for Drupal. Do you know what theme hook I can use?